# indexOf() Showing "-1" In Wrong Circumstance

Tags: javascript, indexof

I am trying to use indexOf() in order to check if a string contains another string and if so it will fire different if statements below is the code and the logged results:

```
  var  str2="Handrail Ext";
  if (fixing.toString().indexOf(str2) === -1 || fixingDig.toString().indexOf(str2) === -1) {
    console.log("$FixingDig: " + fixingDig + " $Fixing: " + fixing + "InfexOf Result: " + fixing.toString().indexOf(str2) + ".");
    $('.results #handrails').val(new_posts);
    $('.wpcf7-form input[name=hidden-post-handrails]').val(new_posts);
  } else {
    console.log("$FixingDig: " + fixingDig + " $Fixing: " + fixing + "InfexOf Result: " + fixing.toString().indexOf(str2) + ".");
    $('.results #handrails').val(0);
    $('.wpcf7-form input[name=hidden-post-handrails]').val("0");
  }
```

**Console Log**

Page Load:

```
$FixingDig: No Fixing. $Fixing: No Fixing. IndexOf Result: -1.
```

Selecting Fixing:

```
$FixingDig: Bolt Down (610mm). $Fixing: No Fixing. IndexOf Result: -1.
```

Selecting Fixing With Handrail:

```
$FixingDig: Bolt Down (760mm + Handrail Ext.). $Fixing: No Fixing. IndexOf Result: -1.
```

Comment: You can see them, str2 is above the code and the input string is displayed in the console logs in the question.

Comment: I don't get it. Where do you think the log is wrong? Because `$Fixing: No Fixing` does not contain `"Handrail Ext"`, therefore the index is -1. The log looks correct to me. What am I missing?

Comment: $FixingDig: Bolt Down (760mm + Handrail Ext.) includes handrail and still returns -1...

Comment: Where? You are not logging this. At least I don't see where.

Comment: I displayed 3 console log messages and highlighted at what point that log was displayed, it very clearly says "Selecting fixing with handrail" then displays the log of a fixing with handrail selected. This has been resolved now anyway.

Comment: You are logging `fixing.indexOf(str2)`, which returns -1, which is correct. But nowhere in the code above are you logging `fixingDig.indexOf(str2)`. It is in the condition, granted, but not in your logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check use `> -1` instead of `=== -1`

```js
var  str = "Handrail Ext";

var text1 = "bla and bla Handrail Ext bla"
var text2 = "bla and bla Handrail bla"

console.log(text1.indexOf(str))
console.log(text2.indexOf(str))
```

Comment: Worked, much appreciated. Can accept as answer shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Your condition `(fixing.toString().indexOf(str2) === -1 || fixingDig.toString().indexOf(str2) === -1)` is wrong.

Case when `fixing = "No Fixing."` and `FixingDig = "No Fixing."`

```
if ("No Fixing.".toString().indexOf("Handrail Ext") === -1 || ...)
//  ^--------------------- True -------------------------^
//  Since the condition is a OR, the remaining isn't evaluated
```

Case when `fixing = "Bolt Down (610mm)."` and `FixingDig = "No Fixing."`

```
if ("Bolt Down (610mm).".toString().indexOf("Handrail Ext") === -1 || ...)
//  ^--------------------------True -----------------------------^
//  Since the condition is a OR, the remaining isn't evaluated
```

Case when `fixing = "Bolt Down (760mm + Handrail Ext.)."` and `FixingDig = "No Fixing."`

```
if ("Bolt Down (760mm + Handrail Ext.).".toString().indexOf("Handrail Ext") === -1 || "No Fixing.".toString().indexOf("Handrail Ext") === -1)
//  ^----------------------------------- False ----------------------------------^    ^---------------------- True ------------------------^
//  Since the condition is a OR, the remaining IS evaluated. The right part is true, the whole condition is TRUE
```

Replace your condition by :

```
if (fixing.toString().indexOf(str2) === -1 && fixingDig.toString().indexOf(str2) === -1)
//            Notice this -----------------^^
```

Try it yourself

```js
console.log("No Fixing No Fixing");

if ("No Fixing".toString().indexOf("Handrail Ext") === -1 && "No Fixing".toString().indexOf("Handrail Ext") === -1) {
    console.log("not found");
  } else {
    console.log("found");
  }
  
console.log("Bolt Down (610mm). No Fixing");
  
if ("Bolt Down (610mm).".toString().indexOf("Handrail Ext") === -1 && "No Fixing".toString().indexOf("Handrail Ext") === -1) {
    console.log("not found");
  } else {
    console.log("found");
  }
  
console.log("Bolt Down (760mm + Handrail Ext.). No Fixing");
  
if ("Bolt Down (760mm + Handrail Ext.).".toString().indexOf("Handrail Ext") === -1 && "No Fixing".toString().indexOf("Handrail Ext") === -1) {
    console.log("not found");
  } else {
    console.log("found");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have used "includes" instead of "indexOf".

Comment: I believe includes throws an object error in IE as it was originally includes but I had to change it to indexOf

Comment: Includes not a cross browser because of IE